# What is a $.wrap parameter (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working with the jquery UI spinoff plugin `selectmenu` from [this github](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu) and the documentation lists something that I'm having a difficult time .... `$.wrapping` my head around.

> wrapperElement: "", Wraps all added elements into a HTML tag. $.wrap parameters accepted.

I don't entirely understand what is going on here. I discovered it because I was trying to find a way to place an `id=""` attribute on the `ul` that the plugin generates so that I can use more specific skinning on a per-needed basis. I tried passing in a jQuery selector and it required the element to already exist, which is counter to what I want to do. So I would write..

```
$(selector).selectmenu({
   wrapperElement: $('#uniqueSelect')
});
```

And my code turns out as ..

```
<select ... >
<div id="uniqueSelect">
   <a class="ui-selectmenu ... ">
</div>

(other parts of the html document)

<div id="uniqueSelect">
   <ul class="ui-selectmenu-menu ...">
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

But what I want to output is ..

```
<select ... >
<a class="ui-selectmenu ... ">

(other parts of the html document)

<div id="uniqueSelect">
   <ul class="ui-selectmenu-menu ...">
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone offer some insight on what this mysterious `wrapperElement` is and how I can make it do this?

Comment: i should +1 you just for the awesome pun :P

Comment: I'm assuming that the "`$.wrap` parameters accepted" documentation means that the attribute can be set to any parameter type accepted by jQuery's `wrap` function: http://api.jquery.com/wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Matt's comment, I think you just need to set your selector properly:

```
$('ul.ui-selectmenu-menu').selectmenu({
  wrapperElement: $('#uniqueSelect')
});
```

The link to the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) on `wrap` that @Matt mentions should help you out.

I'm not sure what your current selector is, so I'm making an assumption here.

Hope this helps.